# R - Wrong references and variable setting

Tags: r, debugging, variables

**Hi there!**

In the following example, there seems to be a problem with the referencing. The code reassembles the calculation of a chess ranking system of a 2v2 game. Each row in "data" is the result of the game

The users table contains all the people who are playing the game. People can play in 6 categories: "INT", "LKS", "SOD", "SJV", "LOY" and "STA". The "sex"-column indicates male/female with either a 0 or a 1 - This column should never be updated.

Data files are supplies in the end of this post.
This is the code I have now:

```
data <- read.csv("data.txt", header=F, quote="")
colnames(data) <- c("user", "p1","p2", "skill","win","looser","time")

data <- data[-which(data$user==data$p1),]
data <- data[-which(data$user==data$p2),]

users <- data.matrix(read.csv("users.txt", header = FALSE, row.names = 1))
colnames(users) <- c("sex", "INT", "LKS", "LOY", "SJV", "SOD", "STA")
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    game <- data[i,]
    winner.old <- users[game$win,    game$skill]
    looser.old <- users[game$looser, game$skill]
    winner.new <- winner.old + 32/2 * (1 - 0 + (1/2) * (looser.old-winner.old) / 200)
    looser.new <- looser.old + 32/2 * (0 - 1 + (1/2) * (winner.old-looser.old) / 200)
    users[game$win,    game$skill] <- winner.new
    users[game$looser, game$skill] <- looser.new
  }
```

The problem is the

```
users[game$win,    game$skill]
```

Which seems to reference the wrong skill column. I've tried to show the problem in the following picture. I'm sorry it's a little messy - but I've tried to color code it! This output is generated from i<-1. Running the entire for loop, you'll see that the STA-column appears "untouched" - it always uses the column to the left, of the one it's supposed to use.

[image]

**data**
http://textuploader.com/o68x

**users.txt**
http://textuploader.com/o68g

Comment: Can you post something simpler that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Ths problem is that the references seems to be wrong, which is seen in the image. Where I get two different results depending on if I type out the value of the variable or just use the variable itself (1201 vs 1202)

Comment: Does `game$skill <- as.character(game$skill)` fix the problem?

Comment: BINGO! Thank you! That seems to have solved the problem! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factors are integers internally and if you use them for subsetting, the internal representation is used:

```
DF <- data.frame(x=1:10)
DF$g <- c("b", "a")
#     x g
# 1   1 b
# 2   2 a
# 3   3 b
# 4   4 a
# 5   5 b
# 6   6 a
# 7   7 b
# 8   8 a
# 9   9 b
# 10 10 a

col <- factor("g", levels=c("g", "x"))

DF[, col]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
as.integer(col)
#[1] 1
```

You need to transform the factor to a character for subsetting:

```
DF[, as.character(col)]
#[1] "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a"
```